# Как сделать метод универсальным с помощью дженериков

Tags: java

Пробую сделать метод importFromJSON универсальным для работы с разными классами. Но что то я запутался я с этими дженериками.

```
private <T> List<T> importFromJSON(DataItems<T> dataItems) { 
  try(FileInputStream fileInputStream = context.openFileInput(fileName);
      InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream)){
  Gson gson = new Gson(); 
  dataItems = gson.fromJson(streamReader, DataItems<>.class); 
  return  dataItems.getList(); 
 } 
 catch (IOException ex){ 
  ex.printStackTrace(); 
 } 
 return null; 
}
```

DataItems.java:

```
public class DataItems<E> { 
 
    private List<E> list; 
 
    public List<E> getList() { 
        return list; 
    } 
 
    public void setList(List<E> list) { 
        this.list = list; 
    } 
}
```

House.java:

```
public class House { 
    int number; 
    String name; 
}
```

Вызываю этот метод уже с конкретным типом

```
DataItems<House> dataItems = new DataItems<>(); 
importFromJSON(dataItems);
```

файл json

```
{"list":[{"name":"01","id":1},{"name":"02","id":2}]}
```

Все читается, в результате выполнения importFromJSON я получаю список объектов, но вот только вместо типа int, там почему то тип Double
И при попытке вытащить из этого списка объект

```
House house = (House) list.get(0);
```

list это переменная класса DataItems.

получаю Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to House
```

Comment: Что такое `list` в выражении `(House) list.get(0);`? Добавьте непосредственно в вопрос, нажав на кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1451625/edit).

Answer (score 4):

1. Информация о типах стирается после компиляции, чтобы правильно передать генерик-тип в ваш метод, используйте [`TypeToken`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html)
2. Уберите неиспользуемый аргумент в методе
3. Не создавайте объект Gson при каждом парсинге
4. Поправьте параметр у House: переименуйте `number` в `id`

Получится такой метод:

```java
private <T> List<T> importFromJson(TypeToken<DataItems<T>> typeToken) {
    try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(...))) {
        DataItems<T> items = gson.fromJson(reader, typeToken.getType());
        return items.getList();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot import from json", exception);
    }
}
```

Работает так:

```java
List<House> houses = importFromJson(new TypeToken<>() {});
House house = houses.get(0);
System.out.println(house);
```

Результат:

```
House{id=1, name='01'}
```